# Adding a defined variable to a private class in PHP

Tags: php, class, private

Why can't I carry a variable ($last_id) into a class?

```
//get value of last sql row
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId():
//create class
Class CropAvatar {
  private $id = $last_id;
  private $src;
  private $dstDir = '../some path';
}
```

private $src and private dstDir works fine.

How can I carry a variable's value into a class?

Comment: Pass the var throught the constructor or create a getter/setter for your class member

Comment: you can't initialize a class attribute with the result of an expression. only constant values, or things that can be treated as constants at compile time. `$id = 42` would work. `$id = $last_id` won't.

Comment: Because `$last_id` is only known at "runtime".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get that value within class like you want. You could achieve your goal by using constructor like below:

```
Class CropAvatar {

  private $id;
  private $src;
  private $dstDir = '../some path';

  public function __construct($last_id) {
    $this->id = $last_id;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use constructor like this:

```
Class CropAvatar {
  private $id;
  private $src;
  private $dstDir = '../some path';
  function __construct($id) {
     $this->id = $id;
  }
}

//get value of last sql row
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId():
$myClass = new CropAvatar($last_id);
```